# responsive design - displaying 2 cards per row on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

**I'm working on a web page where I have a row of cards, each containing an image and a title. Currently, I'm using the Bootstrap grid system to display 4 cards per row on larger screens (col-md-2), and I want to adjust this to show 2 cards per row on small screens.**

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 item mt-3">
                    <div class="card item-card card-block">
                        <img src="~/img/deprt-8.png" style="max-width: 100%; ">

                        <h5 class="item-card-title my-2">Internal/Family Medicine </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 item mt-3">
                    <div class="card item-card card-block">
                    <img src="~/img/deprt-10.png" style="max-width: 100%; ">
                        <h5 class="item-card-title my-2">Pulmonology </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 item mt-3">
                    <div class="card item-card card-block">
                    <img src="~/img/deprt-11.png" style="max-width: 100%; ">
                        <h5 class="item-card-title my-2">Gastroenterology</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 item mt-3">
                    <div class="card item-card card-block">
                    <img src="~/img/deprt-1.png" style="max-width: 100%; ">
                        <h5 class="item-card-title my-2">Dentistry</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `col-sm-4` with `col-sm-6` to show **2** cards on small screens and **1** card on even smaller ones. Or replace `col-sm-4` with `col-6` to show **2** cards on both small and smallest screens.

Change `col-md-2` to `col-md-3` to display **4** cards per row instead of **6** on larger screens.

*Optional:*

Remove unnecessary `style="max-width: 100%; "` from `<img>` and make sure to put a `.row` into container class (such as `.container-fluid`) to avoid parent element overflow (*unless there are additional styles affecting an image and row container layout*).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item mt-3">
      <div class="card item-card card-block">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        <h5 class="item-card-title my-2">Internal/Family Medicine </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item mt-3">
      <div class="card item-card card-block">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        <h5 class="item-card-title my-2">Pulmonology </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item mt-3">
      <div class="card item-card card-block">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        <h5 class="item-card-title my-2">Gastroenterology</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item mt-3">
      <div class="card item-card card-block">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        <h5 class="item-card-title my-2">Dentistry</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```